# how to watch a provider without destroying another

Tags: flutter, riverpod, flutter-riverpod

In my game, I've got a `soundProvider = Provider<MySoundClass>` so various Widgets can command changes to sound.  It stores long-lived audio resources.  I also have a `gameStateProvider = ChangeNotifierProvider<GameState>` holding the game's state.

I'd like `soundProvider` to watch `gameStateProvider`, so that e.g. when the game is won, `soundProvider` can change from playing normal music to playing victory music.

But doing so would trigger a recreation of `soundProvider`'s underlying `MySoundClass` when `gameStateProvider` notified it, which would leak the long-lived audio resources left lying around in the discarded `MySoundClass`.

How should I structure this to prevent the leak but play victory music?  Should I use `ref.listen(gameStateProvider)` callbacks within `soundProvider`, instead of `ref.watch`, to play victory music?  Or should I store the long-held audio resources in a third provider which `soundProvider` watches?  The former seems a little difficult to manage and the latter seems a little too boilerplate.

Comment: How about decoupling the class which holds sound resources and making it singleton?

Comment: @KenWhite Done. Waiting for it to get approved

Comment: @MichealGundlach either of your proposals work (using `ref.listen` or a new third provider). The question is a bit unclear, so it's hard to give a concrete answer.